# Determining a limit graphically (inconsistency with solutions)

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

How would I determine $\lim_{x\to2}[f(x)j(x)]$? I thought it would be $0$ since it seems as though $\lim_{x\to2^-}[f(x)j(x)]=0$ and $\lim_{x\to2^+}[f(x)j(x)]=0$, but apparently the limit does not exist. Can someone point out the error in my reasoning?

Comment: Why do you think that the limits do not exist *apparently*? By deriving their value you *apparently* proved their existence, right?

Comment: @M.Winter I'm convinced that the limit is 0. I think the solution key is off.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<2$ you have $f(x)j(x)=f(x)$, hence $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)j(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)=0$.

For $x>2$ you have $f(x)j(x)=0$ and the limit $x\to 2^+$ is trivially $0$.

So your reasoning seems to be correct.

Comment: Think you mean $\lim_{x\to2^\pm}$ but yeah I think it's just an error in the text.

Comment: @interrogative Of course! Thank you